How to calculate the surface area of breaking strikes?
I am doing an experiment about Pascal's principle where I am breaking boards with my foot. I will put paint/ink on my foot to mark the surface area of what struck the wood.
How can I quantify the precise contact area with the mark left behind by my foot?
